# Find which polygon address lies in

Tags: c#, google-maps, polygon, kml, kmz

I have a custom Google Map in My Maps which has multiple polygons that reflect various regions of route pickup (ex. Monday Pickup Region, Tuesday Pickup Region, etc) and essentially what I want to do is find out which polygon a specific address falls into. This is so that I can figure out what route day a new user is going to belong to with a single button click instead of having to copy address, go to map, paste in, hit search and see what polygon it lands in.

I am completely new to Google Maps and not familiar at all with its API or KML/KMZ files. I see that I can export a self-updating KML or KMZ file, so perhaps I could store that on server and then have program use that to find out what polygon address is in, but I have no idea how to do that with c# or do I need to use javascript and if so how would I do that? Or is there a way I can query google directly via a GET or something?

**UPDATE**
Using the following code I have been able to load the network linked kml file provided by google. Now I am wondering how I can then, with a button click, find which polygon layer from the loaded kml the address entered is in. I'll continue to try and update with what I find.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 39.10342, lng:  -76.87271}
  });

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();
  var kmlUrl =     'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/crew/map/test.kml';
var kmlOptions = {
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  preserveViewport: false,
  map: map
};
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:450px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I ended up with after mix and matching various pieces of information from different sites. It loads the kml stored on server, takes the address that user has input, searches for it in kml's polygons, if it finds it then figures out what day it is, and then sets pick up dropdown appropriately.

Notice that I hid my map and don't set any markers or anything on it; I purely use it to find which polygon address belongs to.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/v3_epoly.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geoXml = null;
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    var toggleState = 1;
    var infowindow = null;
    var marker = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
  infowindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({size: new window.google.maps.Size(150,50) });
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(43.502745, -116.240845),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: window.google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);
  geoXml = new window.geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true, infoWindow: infowindow});

  geoXml.parse('map/routemap-v2.kml');
}
function showAddress() {
    var address = $("#<%=txtCustomerAddress.ClientID%>").val() + ', ' + $("#<%=txtCustomerCity.ClientID%>").val() + ', ' + $("#<%=txtCustomerState.ClientID%>").val() + ' ' + $("#<%=txtCustomerZipcode.ClientID%>").val();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var point = results[0].geometry.location;

          for (var i=0; i<geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons.length; i++) {
              if (geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[i].Contains(point)) {
                  var layerName = geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[i].name;
                  var day = "";
                  if (layerName.indexOf("Monday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Monday";
                  }
                  else if (layerName.indexOf("Tuesday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Tuesday";
                  }
                  else if (layerName.indexOf("Wednesday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Wednesday";
                  }
                  else if (layerName.indexOf("Thursday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Thursday";
                  }
                  else if (layerName.indexOf("Friday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Friday";
                  }
                  else if (layerName.indexOf("Saturday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Saturday";
                  }
                  else if (layerName.indexOf("Sunday") >= 0) {
                      day = "Sunday";
                  } else {
                      day = layerName;
                  }
                  $("#<%=PickUpDay.ClientID%>").val(day);
                  i = 999; // exit loop
          }
        }
        } else {
            alert("Address, as inputed, is not within the limits of any of the current routes. Please manually consult pick up day or edit address and try again.");
        }
    });
    }
</script>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 0; height: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; border:1px solid #999; display: none"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm getting at is you want to know at which polygon an address will fall in to. If this is the case then [`containsLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation) can be beneficial for you. Pass the address' `latlng` value to each polygon and see if that coords are inside one or not.

Sort of like this

```
var polygons = [];

function checkIfPartOfPolygon(addressLatLng, polygon){
    return google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle);
}

function foo(){
    var address = {};
    for (var i=0; i<polygons.length; i++){
        var addressPartOfPolygon = checkIfPartOfPolygon(address.latlng, polygons[i]);
        if (addressPartOfPolygon){
            //address is part of current polygon, do something here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

An official sample for containsLocation can be found on the [documentation's sample section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)